# Using camera and geolocation in react native webview

Tags: react-native, webview

I would like to use html5 webcam and geolocation when I open webview inside React native app.

```
   <WebView geolocationEnabled={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
```

solves problem for webview geolocation but says it only works on android and I would like to find general solution for ios as well.

How can I force webview to use camera and enable geolocation on ios as well?

Comment: have you solved this issue?